# Get form fields data on form submission using forminator plugin

Tags: forms

I need to get form’s fields data of submitted/current form on form submission

I trying with these hooks
forminator_form_after_handle_submit/forminator_form_after_save_entry

trying this

```
add_action( ‘forminator_form_after_save_entry’, ‘function_Name’ );
function function_Name( $form_id, $response ) {
  // code here
}
```

but when submitting form get this issue

```
An error occurred while processing the form. Please try again
```

log error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function function_Name(), 1 passed in D:\xampp\htdocs\sos_wp\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 312 and exactly 2 expected in D:\xampp\htdocs\sos_wp\wp-content\themes\sos-theme\functions.php:86
```

can someone help with this
Thanks
Dinesh

Comment: Questions about 3rd party plugins are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope, if you need help developing for a plugin you downloaded/bought you need to ask elsewhere. You're lucky the cause of this is a mistake with `add_action`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I can't comment on Forminator on this stack, there is a basic mistake involving `add_action` causing the error message in your log.

The cause of this is that your function requires 2 arguments to work, but you did not tell `add_action` this, so it used the default 1:

> add_action( string $hook_name, callable $callback, int $priority = 10, int ***$accepted_args = 1*** ): true

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

You need to specify that your function takes 2 arguments when using `add_action` using the 4th argument, e.g.

```php
add_action( ‘test_action’, ‘callback’, 10, 2 );
```

Additionally, the quotation marks in the code in your question are using smart quotes `‘...’`, use `"..."` or `'...'` instead

Answer (score 2):

I did some more research & find this can get form feilds with $_POST

```
add_action( 'forminator_form_after_handle_submit', 'function_Name', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'forminator_form_after_save_entry', 'function_Name', 10, 2 );

function function_Name($form_id, $response) {
    if( $response['success'] ){
        error_log(print_r($_POST, true));
    }
}
```